# D3 transition between line interpolations

Tags: d3.js, transition, interpolation

I have been searching for quite a while but I haven't been able to figure it out.

I want to have a transition between two interpolations "basis" and "step-after" for a single line.

```
var time_scale, kpi_scale;
var line;

var data = [
{"kpi": 100, "time": 1317448800000},
{"kpi": 200, "time": 1320127200000},
{"kpi": 250, "time": 1322719200000},
{"kpi": 180, "time": 1325397600000},
{"kpi": 230, "time": 1328076000000},
{"kpi": 360, "time": 1330581600000},
{"kpi": 140, "time": 1333260000000},
{"kpi": 120, "time": 1335852000000},
{"kpi": 240, "time": 1338530400000},
{"kpi": 190, "time": 1341122400000},
{"kpi": 185, "time": 1343800800000},
{"kpi": 130, "time": 1346479200000},
{"kpi": 340, "time": 1349071200000},
{"kpi": 320, "time": 1351749600000},
{"kpi": 250, "time": 1354341600000}
];

// set up the viewport, the scales, and axis generators      
var container_dimensions = {width: 900, height: 400},
    margins = {top: 10, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 60},
    chart_dimensions = {
        width: container_dimensions.width - margins.left - margins.right,
        height: container_dimensions.height - margins.top - margins.bottom
    };

var time_extent = d3.extent(
    data,
    function(d){return d.time;}
);

time_scale = d3.time.scale()
    .domain(time_extent)
    .range([0, chart_dimensions.width]);

var kpi_extent = d3.extent(
    data,
    function(d){return d.kpi;}
);

kpi_scale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(kpi_extent)
    .range([chart_dimensions.height, 0]);

var container = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
        .attr("width", container_dimensions.width)
        .attr("height", container_dimensions.height)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margins.left + "," + margins.top + ")")
        .attr("id","chart");

draw_timeseries (data);
transitionToStepped (data);

function draw_timeseries (data) {
    line = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d){return time_scale(d.time);})
        .y(function(d){return kpi_scale(d.kpi);})
        .interpolate("basis");

    d3.select('#chart').append('path')
        .attr('d', line(data))
        .attr('id', 'line')
        .attr('class', 'line');               
}

function transitionToStepped (data) {

    line.interpolate("step-after");

    d3.select("#chart").selectAll(".line")
        .transition()
        .duration(2000)
        .attr("d", line(data))
        .delay(2000);           
}
```

I have saved a small jsfiddle containing my code.

[jsFiddle Interpolation Transition](http://jsfiddle.net/flyingk/4Y4ef/)

I wanted to "morph" between the basis line and the step-after line. But d3 is sliding in the step-after line from the left instead of "bending" the basis line into a step-after one.

Thanks for your help.
Christoph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has got to be a way to do this, and certainly one better than the offering below (I am looking forward to seeing other answers), but I have seen no answers here as of yet, and this will at least do a "morph" for you, although it also makes the line parallel to the x-axis during the transition. Not a terrible thing, but I believe not precisely what you are after.

Here's a fiddle for the full code and demo, 
modified from your original:
http://jsfiddle.net/n5P6z/2/

The meat of the approach is here:

```
function xLineReduce() {
    line.x(function (d) {
        return time_scale(d.time);
    }).y(function (d) {
        return chart_dimensions.height;
    });
}

function resetInterpolator() {
    line.interpolate("cubic-in-out");
}

function stepItUp() {
    line.x(function (d, i) {
        return time_scale(d.time);
    })
        .y(function (d, i) {
        return kpi_scale(d.kpi);
    })
        .interpolate("step-after");
}

function transitionToStepped(myData) {
    path.data(myData)
        .call(xLineReduce)
        .transition()
        .delay(1000)
        .duration(500)
        .attr('d', line(myData));

    path.data(myData)
        .call(resetInterpolator)
        .transition()
        .delay(1500)
        .duration(0)
        .attr('d', line(myData));

    path.data(myData)
        .call(stepItUp)
        .transition()
        .delay(1500)
        .duration(500)
        .attr('d', line(myData));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your proposal. As you have mentioned the transition is not exactly what I want, but nevertheless useful. My current approach is to do a transition between "interpolated" line chart and bar chart by changing the opacity (fading out and in at the same time), which makes it easier to see that the data behind the line and the bars is the same.